# Round Robin routee's not recieving messages randomly

Tags: akka

I am using akka 2.3.0 round robin pool

deployment
   /EventProcessorRouter
    router = round-robin-pool
   nr-of-instances = 65

Topic's Look up using

```
 ActorRef transformerRouter = getContext().actorFor("akka://appName/user/EventProcessorRouter");
 transformerRouter.tell(munibondAnalyticsEvent, transformerRouter);
```

I have one consumer actor recieveing messages from topic and pushing to the processor actor via Round robin router. I have set defined the round robin router with 65 instances.

I am getting a load of 11K and when it processes out of which 150 messages sent to the round robin router from the topic reciever actor but its not making to the processor actor and rest are processed fine. Not sure why these messages are not processed by routee's ever.

What could be the reason these messages could be lost? I checked for any actors crashing and i dont see any actor crashing as i have implemented postStop in my actor so if it has crashed i will see logging in my logs.

Please suggest me what could cause it.

Comment: if an exception occurs the actor will be restarted per default, not stopped, so I would expect your postStop method is only called during shutdown. You can implement preRestart or postRestart to deal with this. In any case, exceptions are logged, so if you do not see anything in your logs, you probably have no problem with exceptions.

Comment: So if an actor is restarted would all the messages in the mailbox for the actor would be lost?

Comment: No, the Mailbox and the ActorRef are independent of the actor instance (tied together by what is called Actor Incarnation, see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Actor_Lifecycle). When restarting a new instance will be created and will process all messages left in the mailbox. The message that caused the exception will be lost though.

Comment: Thank you for the details. But the problem i am running here is that actors processes majority of the messages but few messages i see actors work on them after a pause and in this case they were just missed. and aorund 140 messages didnt even reach the actor. I am logging when i am sending from the topic reciever actor and it is sent to the ref of round robin router but it never made to the processing actor. Had it reached it would have logged the details. I am not finding any exceptions as well. Not sure whats going on inside and why these messages are lost. Any clue would help.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. Akka guarantees that each message will be delivered at most once, so basically there is no guarantee that all messages reach the actors. However, if you have no remoting or clustering there are very few cases where messages are lost. Is there anything different about the messages that are lost?

Comment: Nope i dont see anything different. As i have posted i just get the actor ref using the above mentioned code and pass the message. And i am logging the message bfore after sending it. And i log the incoming message detail in the next actor but i dont see this message coming into the next actor. And i dont see any exceptions as well. Its kinda  wierd.

Comment: Thanks for yuor comments and suggestions. It was a problem with actor's processing logic where it went into looping and hence these messages were queued up and never reached the actor.